# C# How to add placement variable into a resource string

Tags: c#, resources

This should be easy, but can't find anything to explain it.

Say I am writing something out on console.writeln like:

`console.writeln("Jim is a  {0} ", xmlscript);`

Say I wanted to convert string `"Jim is.." to a resource string in a global resource.resx. It would be:

`jimstring jim is a {0}`

and I would refer to it in code as

`console.writeln(Resources.jimstring)`

How to I put the placement variable (`xmlscript`) (is this what they are called?) into the resource string in console.writeln?

Thanks,

Bob

Comment: I've got this

if (Logger.RuleLoadingInformation)
{
string formattedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss:fffff");
                    Logger.RuleLoadingSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, formattedDate + ": " + Resources.jimstring);
                }

Would it be a case of having to do some kind of stringbuilder or string format before I send the TraceEvent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As Jeff Johnson mentioned in his answer, it basically the exact same thing as the original Console.WriteLine().  The resource string is just a string.  So you reference the resource file and do the format.

If you need it for something other than the Console you can use the String.Format():

```
  var newString = String.Format(resources.jimstring, xmlscript);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Console.WriteLine(Resources.jimstring, xmlscript);
```

Console.WriteLine takes additional formatting arguments that will replace the {0} in your Resources.jimstring string.

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h.aspx

Comment: What would happen if you put it into a TraceEvent like
TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 0, formattedDate + ": " + Resources.jimstring)

for some reason I can't get it to work. 
Bob.

Comment: Can you add this code to your original question? What is the type of formattedDate?